# Alignments in CSS3 flexbox

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox

I am working on React/Redux  e-commerce project, project uses Flexbox for layout and designing, I have a knowledge of React but I am new to CSS3 flexbox, I have to achieve a layout in flexbox, 90% is complete but not able to align some elements, my React code, SCSS code and expected and actual designs are posted below, can any one help me to achieve this layout,thanks in advance

only I have to place item **(AED 325 above the quantity)** with the help of flexbox

---

**CSS Code**

```
.modalHeaderWrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  flex-direction: row;
  border-bottom: solid 1px $color-border;

   .left {
     flex: 3;
     background-color: $color-bg-primary;
   }

   .right {
     flex: 1;
     flex-direction: column;
     background-color: $gray-bg;
     border-top: 1px solid $_greyLight;
     border-right: 1px solid $_greyLight;
     border-left: 1px solid $_greyLight;

     .modalCartSummary {
       text-align: center;
       margin-top: 30px;
     }
   }
}



.aed {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: $_offBlack;
}

.productBox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;

    .modalProductName {
      font-size: 14px;
      color: $_offBlack;
      text-align: left;
      line-height: 17px;
    }
}

.modalProductSummary {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.shippingSellerWrapperModal {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: -13px !important
}

.modalImage {
  height: 74px;
  width: auto;
  margin-left: 17px;
}
```

---

**React code**

```
<div className={styles.modalHeaderWrapper}>
    <div className={styles.left}>
        <div className={styles.type}>
          <div className={styles.productAddTitle}>
              <Icon name="radio-checked" className={styles.check} />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.productBox}>
          <div>
              <img src={Helper.getTransformationUrl(product.image_keys[0])} className={styles.modalImage} alt="new"/>
          </div>
          <div className={styles.modalProductSummary}>
              <div className={styles.modalProductName}>
                  {product.product_title}
              </div>
              <div className={styles.reviewbadge}>

                    <div className={styles.reviewCtr}>
                        <ProductReviewsBadge
                            reviewData={this.props.reviewsSummary}
                        />
                    </div>
              </div>
              {this.renderProductSubComponent('shippingEstimator', product, offer)}
              <div className={styles.shippingSellerWrapperModal}>

              </div>
          </div>
          <div className={styles.qntAndPriceBlock}>
              AED 325
              {I18n.getText('cart.cart-modal-qty', {qty: quantity}, 'quantity {qty}')}
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div className={styles.right}>
        <div className={styles.modalCartSummary}>
            <p className={styles.itemsNumber}>
                 'your cart has worth 
            </p>
            <span className={styles.aed}>
                AED
            </span>
            <span>
              <strong className={styles.value}>
                  {I18n.formatCurrency(this.props.cartSummary.grandTotal.value)}
              </strong>
            </span>
        </div>

        <div className={styles.btnWrapper}>
            <Button className={styles.modalBtn} onClick={() => browserHistory.push('/' + this.props.locale.locale)}>
                {I18n.getText('account.profile-address-cancel', {}, 'VIEW CART')}
            </Button>
            <Button className={styles.modalBtn} variant="transparent" onClick={this.closeModal}>
                {I18n.getText('account.profile-address-cancel', {}, 'CONTINUE SHOPPING')}
            </Button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Actual Outcome**

[image: Actual Outcome]

**Expected Outcome**

[image]

**Responsive view**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrap the "AED 325" and the "{I18n.getText('cart.cart-modal-qty', {qty: quantity}, 'quantity {qty}')}" and then set up a `qntAndPriceBlock` rule with

```
.qntAndPriceBlock {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;       /*  stack the flex items vertically  */
  align-items: flex-end;        /*  right align flex column items  */
}
```

Stack snippet

```css
.qntAndPriceBlock {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class='qntAndPriceBlock'>
  <div>AED 325</div>
  <div>{I18n.getText('cart.cart-modal-qty', {qty: quantity}, 'quantity {qty}')}</div>
</div>
```

---

As the `.productBox` appears to be a flex row container, and as that will also make the `.qntAndPriceBlock` a flex item, you might also need to add `flex-grow: 1` to it so it takes full width

```
.qntAndPriceBlock {
  flex-grow: 1;                 /*  take available space left  */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;       /*  stack the flex items vertically  */
  align-items: flex-end;        /*  right align flex column items  */
}
```

Comment: Thanks LGSon, but how to align AED 320 and quantity block in product summary in responsive view, i have edited with image, can you please help, Thanks in advance

Comment: @faizy Setting `align-items` to `flex-start` should solve that. And I assume you have a media query or similar that does that?

Comment: Yes, i do have media queries, but image, product summary and qty are different blocks, now these three blocks are align in row, but my question is how to align qty block in between star ratings and estimated deleivery

Comment: @faizy First, that requirement is not in your initial question, second, you mean be positioned after the `<div className={styles.reviewbadge}>` element?

Comment: Sorry, for not updating my question, yes i want to position below the shipping badge

Comment: @faizy As the markup is now, you'll need a script...or double up the `.qntAndPriceBlock` element and then show/hide the one you need visible using the media query.